# Getting Python range() to recognise a decimal eg. 70.555555

Tags: python, python-3.x, floating-point, range, decimal-point

Using Python 3.4 and I have a list which has numbers in it which have 8 decimal places or more (eg. -72.2373909452 and 175.33903215), and I need a way to separate them according to their number.

Original code looks like this:

```
for number in list:
    range_list=[]
    if number in range(x, y):
        range_list.append(number)
```

but for obvious reasons it doesn't work and doesn't add any numbers to the new list.

I also thought about multiplying the number first and then just having the range numbers between factors of ten, but as the number of decimal places is different between each number that isn't practical.

Comment: Don't use `list` as variable name.

Comment: I'm not using list as a variable name, that was just as an example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand well, you want to check if `number` is between `x` and `y`.

Just use comparisons then. The following has the same behavior the "`number in range(x, y)`" solution has with integers:

```
if x <= number < y:
    range_list.append(number)
```

Even if `number` is an integer, this sort of comparison is clearer and most likely faster than the solution involving `range`.

On a side note, you should define `range_list` outside of the `for` loop, otherwise you'll end up emptying the list with each loop:

```
range_list=[]
for number in my_list:
    if x <= number < y:
        range_list.append(number)
```